# How to create multiple buffers around line at equal intervals without typing in every value?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, buffer

I have a line in ArcMap 10.2, and want to create lines to the right of it at 100 m, 200 m, 300 m etc. up until 1.7 km. Obviously typing in these values under 'multiple ring buffers' will take too much time. Is there a way for ArcMap to compute this automatically across the equal intervals?

If you could answer through basic ArcMap methods that would be great. I do not understand the coding language that some of you use!

Answer (score 10):

I made a custom [Create Buffer Interval toolbox](http://ianbroad.com/download/toolbox/CreateBufferIntervals.tbx) for you:

In ArcMap open ArcToolbox, right click in the whitespace and click Add Toolbox. Browse to the one I made and run the Create Buffer at Interval tool.

Here's a screenshot of the parameters:

[image]

It should be pretty straightforward, but let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: +1 You may want to consider uploading your tool to the [**Analysis and Geoprocessing Tool Gallery**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/analysis/017z0000001q000000.htm).