# drawing concentric circles in arcmap 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, map-drawing, circle, spatial-query

I am using ArcMap 10.1 and I would like to know if there is a way to draw circles at a specific distance from a georeferenced coordinate. I have a property and I would like to know how far you can walk from it within different amounts of time, and I would like to portray this with multiple circles.

Answer (score 7):

Basically, this is just [Buffer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000019000000). Since you want to make multiple buffers at once, though, the [Multiple Ring Buffer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Multiple_Ring_Buffer/00080000001p000000/) tool would be more appropriate.
[image: Multi ring buffer]
and the default will be the crs/gcs of the input unless you change it with the unit option.

It's worth considering that plain distance is not walking distance. Walking routes are restricted: a person can't (reasonably) walk over a building, an interstate highway, a river/stream, etc., and it's harder to walk up a steep hill than along a level path. A more accurate analysis would use [Cost Distance tools](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000018000000.htm), which are basically Euclidean Distance plus additional considerations -- but you'd need additional data (land cover, or slope, etc.).

Buffers will give you a very reasonable approximation, however!

Comment: Also see [This Answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/91354/15768) for a Arc tool that can make buffers given a range and interval -- easier than Multiple Ring Buffer for a large enough number of buffers!

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000) tool, with different buffer distances, will yield circles around your point.

If you want accurate walking time polygons, and have a Network Analyst license, look into [Service Area Analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Service_area_analysis/004700000048000000/)

Answer (score 0):

I think buffer analysis in arcpy could work. The following is a sample code based on the center coordinate:

```
# For instance, if you want to build buffer based on a city's railway station
class MTR_Station(object):

    # Load some class variables
    # Class variables, which include
    # tpu area shapefile
    tpu_4326 = 'tpu_4326.shp'
    # the center of each transit neighborhood
    tn_points = 'tn_in_tpu.shp'
    # the tweets shapefile
    tweets = 'tweets_in_tpu.shp'

    def __init__(self, station_name):
        self.station_name = station_name

    def create_buffer(self, buffer_radius, saving_path, saved_file_name):
        # The 'tn_points_lyr' could only be created for once. So add a try except pair
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=MTR_Station.tn_points, out_layer='tn_points_lyr')
        buffer_argument = str(buffer_radius) + ' Miles'
        selected_layer = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view='tn_points_lyr',
                                                                     selection_type='NEW_SELECTION',
                                                                     where_clause=""" "Name" = '{}' """.format(
                                                                         self.station_name))
        # create buffer
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features=selected_layer,
                                  out_feature_class=os.path.join(saving_path, saved_file_name),
                                  buffer_distance_or_field=buffer_argument,
                                  line_side="FULL",
                                  line_end_type="ROUND",
                                  dissolve_option="NONE",
                                  dissolve_field="",
                                  method="PLANAR")
```