# Split overlapping buffer polygons into zones

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, buffer, overlapping-features, splitting

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 and
I need to calculate the mean altitude in some zones around specific points.
I used buffer tool for the desired distances from the point/center, but overlapping polygons have been created. I would like to keep only the zones between the predefined distances as individual polygons.
For example, I buffered at distances 2, 5, 10, 50, 150 meters and the corresponding polygons have been created. I would like to keep somehow individual polygons/zones/sections as following:
0-2m
2-5m
5-10
10-50
50-150
in order to calculate after the mean altitude in them.

Is there any way?

Preferably using toolbox procedures.

Comment: You can Erase 150 with 50, Erase 50 with 10, etc. Merge the outputs.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Feature to Polygon tool. This will create new polygons where polygons overlap. Select which ones you need.

Answer (score 1):

I try to list a few options for ArcGIS Desktop.

You can buffer your first buffer iteratively by selecting line_side option **Outside Only** and merge the all resulting polygons. For example create your first 2m buffer from the point and then use this output as the input to the next buffer iteration for 5m but selecting specified line side option. However this option is available in Advanced licence.

Another way is to use [Multiple Ring Buffer tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/multiple-ring-buffer.htm), but this may process pretty slow if you have many points.

Lastly you may want to give it a go a custom tool [as mentioned in this post.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91345/how-to-create-multiple-buffers-around-line-at-equal-intervals-without-typing-in)